# Dismissing a ViewControll Upwards instead of downwards

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am presenting a simple modal ViewController calling

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueLogOut" sender:nil];
```

However when i dismiss it I want it to move upwards instead of downwards, it it possible?

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

**EDIT:**

I tried to make a custom animation, It didn't work really well. The background stays black until the modal is dismissed...

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    } ];
```

Comment: Yes, but not with any built in method. You have to do your own animation, then call dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:, and pass NO for the animation.

Comment: I am trying to do it to do a custom animation, however the back stays black until i dismiss the modal...

Comment: That's because there's nothing behind the view, except the window itself. You need to insert the previous controller's view beneath the modal's view first, then do your animation.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, to change the `presentViewController` animation style, you set a `modalTransitionStyle` property on the `viewController`.

ref: https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalTransitionStyle

However, to answer your question, none of the (*few*) `modalTransitionStyle`s have a predefined style to animate upwards.

You need to do the animation yourself.